# Race condition creating directory with New-Item?

Tags: windows, powershell

I'm seeing a race condition when calling New-Item to create a directory on a foreign machine using a UNC path. The code is below:

```
New-Item $target -itemType Directory -Force -Verbose |
        %{ Write-Host "Creating dir" $_.FullName }
```

Using Test-Path immediately afterwards returns false. I put a Test-Path -> sleep for 1 second retry loop and after sleeping for 1 second, Test-Path is returning true.

Is New-Item a blocking call? Should I expect to have to wait after calling New-Item?

Comment: I have no problems and get a result of true: md \\server\share\newFolder; test-path \\server\share\newFolder

Comment: Ditto, no problem here creating directories & testing 50 times in rapid succession.  Maybe there is something unusual about your network share (like a caching layer)?

Comment: @Niall Are you doing this against a DFS share? though why you'd be going to different shares from one instruction to the other i don't know...

Comment: No, it's not a DFS share as far as I'm aware (not my area of expertise). I ran similar tests and saw it working fine as well, but when the same action is taken during a deployment script we run, we see the behaviour that it can sometimes take up to 3 sleep/retry loops (1 second each) to recognise the folder as created. Perhaps the deployment script puts enough load on the server file system that some caching anomalies are seen. No idea.

Answer (score 1):

I cannot reproduce your problem.

```
PS > New-Item "test" -itemType Directory -Force -Verbose | %{ Test-Path $_.FullName }
VERBOSE: Performing the operation "Create Directory" on target "Destination: C:\Users\Frode\Desktop\test".
True
```

`New-Item` creates a new directory by getting a [DirectoryInfo](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/System.IO.DirectoryInfo(v=vs.110).aspx)-object for the parent directory, and calling it's [CreateSubDirectory](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/h8dtw1d6%28v=vs.110%29.aspx), like:

```
DirectoryInfo subdirectory = new DirectoryInfo(parentPath).CreateSubdirectory(childName);
```

I'm not a developer, but AFAIK that means it's a blocking call, since it waits for an `DirectoryInfo`-object in return. So mabe the problem is with your storage subsystem.

Answer (score 0):

Try running the `New-Item` command in another process and wait for it:

`` Start-Process powershell -Argument "-Command `"New-Item `"$myNewDir`" -ItemType `"directory`"`"" -NoNewWindow -Wait ``

I was writing a script that would create a folder and then write a 7zip archive to the folder but 7zip would complain that the directory did not exist. This seemed to work around the issue.